# Ubuntu 18.04 monitoring connected devices on wifi

Tags: 18.04, wireless

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04 and i have a huawei box for my internet. 
Could you please suggest me a tool to monitor which devices are connected to my wifi. 
It would be fine if it's not a tool with GUI but only using command line. 
Of course i've tried to go to the setting page of the box but it is not working out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [nmap](https://nmap.org/) to get a list of the devices connected.

You can find the information about using it [here, on itsfoss](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-find-what-devices-are-connected-to-network-in-ubuntu/) and [on howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/423709/how-to-see-all-devices-on-your-network-with-nmap-on-linux/).

But the TL;DR is:

- Install nmap `sudo apt-get install nmap`
- Get your ip address via `ip a`
- Assuming you get an output like `inet 192.168.1.104/24`
- Run `sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24` to get the list of devices connected on your network.
- Further, you can use something like the `watch` command to schedule the process to run continuously to view the list devices at all time.

I'd recommend you go through the blogs to understand how it works.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it showed the mac address of all the connected devices. And all the other link are very useful ! @dotdeb